# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must not be null

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

after I added Eureka to my application I get this error:

```
2022-03-02 23:57:13.067 ERROR 15068 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw except
ion [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must not be null] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source must not be null
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:757) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.copyProperties(BeanUtils.java:701) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
        at cdg.releve.persistence.mongodb.adapter.ReleveBancaireSpringMongodbAdapter.getReleveBancaireById(ReleveBancaireSpringMongodbAdapter.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
        at cdg.releve.application.service.adapter.ReServiceAdapter.getReById(ReleveBancaireServiceAdapter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
        at cdg.releve.infrastructure.rest.controller.ReControllerImpl.getReById(ReleveBancaireControllerImpl.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
```

Here I was sending endpoints request and I get Status: 500 internal Server error. Before adding eureka client it was working greate just after adding eureka dependency this happened.

This is my project structure

```
+ -- MyMainProject
     + -- application           <- Module 1
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- domain                <- Module 2
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- bootloader            <- Module 3
     |     `src/main/java/BootloaderApplicationLuncher (Java application launcher)
     |     ` -- pom.xml
     + -- infrastructure        <- Module 4 (has 3 modules)
          + -- infrastructure 1          <- Module 4.1
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 2          <- Module 4.2
          |     `  --  pom.xml
          + -- infrastructure 3          <- Module 4.3
          |     `  --  pom.xml
     | -- pom.xml
```